# 'Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed'

Tags: hard-drive, boot, memory, ssd, bios

I  have a Lenovo Y350 laptop. Last night I (wrongly, I now know) removed the Intel Optaine Memory and intended to replace that with 256Gb of SSD.

I removed the Intel Optaine Memory, then thought it would be best to run in safe mode before I continued (I now know this was too late) I clipped back in the Optaine Memory, turned on my laptop, and I am now faced with the error message.

'Default Boot Device Missing or Bootfailed'

I've read into this issue further. I understand that in the BIOS setup, I may be able to run the Boot mode as a legacy instead of UEFI to resolve this? the option is greyed out - even when I disable OS Optimized defaults & disable secure boot.

I've checked my SATA disk status in the BIOS configuration, and it is disabled. Is this also part of the issue?

My question summed up. I turned off my laptop, removed the Intel Optaine Memory, clipped in the memory again straight after (before even turning it on). Then I turned my laptop on. Faced with: 'Default Boot Device Missing or Bootfailed' error. How can I start my laptop up using windows again? Is this possible without having to reset the hard drive or do a factory reset?

Comment: If Windows was installed on a GPT disk the you must use UEFI.  Optane requires UEFI based on my research.  Legacy mode is dead.  The device was turned off when the Optane drive was removed?  [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: The device was turned off when optaine was removed - I'm just hoping now that the laptop wasn't in sleep mode? And yes I've also done some research. You're right, if intel optaine memory is used UEFI is required.

Comment: If the laptop was in 'sleep mode' and not powered off properly (im almost positive it was) maybe I have corrupt?

Comment: Optane should have only been used as a cache drive. It was only between 16 GB and 32 GB and neither are large enough to be the boot drive.

Comment: That's what I thought also - the optaine is 16GB.  On the information tab in the BIOS next to hard disk it says: NOT DETECTED do you know of a way to link up the harddisk correctly again?

Comment: Are you sure it’s properly installed. It should be detected.  I assume the actual system disk is detected?

Comment: I hope it should be, I only unclipped the intel optaine memory.In the configuration tab in the BIOS. under controller mode: Intel Rapid Storage Technology > incomplete volume member disks > SATA 931. Gb is displayed so must be able to read it

Comment: You unclipped it?

Comment: Sorry unclipped as in removed the optaine memory from its slot on the motherboard

Comment: Optane isn’t SATA; Screenshots are necessary at this point

Comment: Try to remove the Optane Memory and reboot.

Comment: Good suggestion! Thanks. Still presented with the same error.  The bios configuration menu shows me the hard drive is 'disabled'. I guess with the removal of the optaine memory, i might be able to change the laptops bootmode to 'legacy'?